# Scaling graphics in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, graphics

I am writing a scheduling-type application using Qt/C++ and want to display weekly schedules in one part of the window, and have this rendering scale as the window size increases. The renders will be composed of rectangles with text in them, and as the display area increases the rectangles should scale nicely while the text should remain the same size.

I have experimented with QGraphicsScene and QGraphicsView and I can make rectangles and text scale; however, the rectangle scaling seems ugly (stretches the outline) and I don't want text to scale at all.

I suspect that I might want to resize the scene to the display area and re-draw the rectangles and text; however, I am not sure how to do this - QGraphicsScene doesn't seem to respond to resizeEvent. Is this even the right approach?

Comment: A regular `QHBoxLayout` with `QLabel`s seems to be satisfying.

Comment: I was thinking of not using QGraphicsScene and QGraphicsView at all, but I wanted these renderings to eventually be printable. Is it possible/easier to print areas that just use layouts/other widgets?

Comment: Printing widgets is [pretty simple](http://qt-project.org/faq/answer/how_can_i_print_a_widget) in Qt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what the ugly rectangle scaling is about (a screenshot might help me understand better what you meant there), but if you don't want the text parts to scale, you can accomplish that by calling setFlag(ItemIgnoresTransformations, true) on your QTextGraphicItem objects.

As far as automatically rescaling the rectangles in response to a window resize, you might take a look at the documentation of the [QGraphicsView::fitInView()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qgraphicsview.html#fitInView) method:

> Scales the view matrix and scrolls the scroll bars to ensure that the
>   scene rectangle rect fits inside the viewport [...] It's common to
>   call fitInView() from inside a reimplementation of resizeEvent(), to
>   ensure that the whole scene, or parts of the scene, scales
>   automatically to fit the new size of the viewport as the view is
>   resized. Note though, that calling fitInView() from inside
>   resizeEvent() can lead to unwanted resize recursion, if the new
>   transformation toggles the automatic state of the scrollbars. You can
>   toggle the scrollbar policies to always on or always off to prevent
>   this (see horizontalScrollBarPolicy() and verticalScrollBarPolicy()).

Comment: Setting the flag for the text worked great - thanks!
The "ugly scaling" problem I was referring to was a black outline that would appear and would be an uneven width on each of the sides; I can fix this by using `rect1->setPen(QPen(Qt::NoPen));` Is there a way to not let the outline scale, e.g. always have it fixed at say 2px wide?

Comment: Also, rectangles seem to "shimmer" 1px left and right as they scale. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Try calling setCosmetic(true) on your QPen object before passing it to setPen().

Comment: Thanks for all the help! One last question - I set the text to ignore transformations, but I need to get the length and width of the untransformed text to properly place it in the scene. However, `text->boundingRect()` appears to return the rectangle of the text if it were transformed, not the dimensions of the text on-screen. Is there any way to get the actual displayed dimensions in terms of scene height and width?

Comment: I don't know of an elegant way to do it, but if you're okay with an ugly way, how about taking the transformed rectangle and un-transforming it:  QRect untransformedRect = myGraphicsView->matrix().inverted().mapRect(transformedRect);